# Prove or reject my solution to "How quickly can you type this unary string?"

Tags: optimization, algorithms, recursive-algorithms, integer-sequences

I had posted an answer on the [Code Golf SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) yesterday. Although the answer on that site remain valid if no counterexample can be find. I'm interesting in its correctness. So I want to find a prove or counterexample to my solution. While, answer this question do not involve any skill about programming, but only some math work about integers. So, don't panic.

You may find the [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271793/how-quickly-can-you-type-this-unary-string/) authed by [emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a) on Code Golf SE, and [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271793/how-quickly-can-you-type-this-unary-string/271795). But let me briefly restate the question:

### Question

One want to type $n$ letter `a`'s on an editor. The editor starts with no content in it, and an empty clipboard. In each step, the user may:

- `A`: Type a letter `a`, so there is one more letter `a` in the editor.
- `C(k)`: Copy `k` letter `a`'s into the clipboard. $k$ must be less than or equals to the number of characters currently in the editor. The clipboard now have $k$ letter `a`'s in it.
- `V`: Paste the clipboard to the editor content. So the editor have $k$ more `a`'s in it. $k$ is the number of characters we just sent to the clipboard.

And the question is to implement the function $f(x)$, where $x\in\mathbb{N}^+$ is the number of `a` we want to type, and $f(x)$ is the minimal steps we need.

An example is $f(17)=8$, which can be shown as: `AAA C(3)VV C(8)V`.

And the first 30 terms have shown in the question:

```
1,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,9,10,10,10
```

Notice that this function is *not* monotone, as $f(27)=9<10=f(26)$.

### My Solution

My solution is define the function as (to not confuse with the $f$, let's denote it as $g$)

$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
n & n<6 \\
\min \left\{g\left(n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)+2, g\left(n-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)+3 \right\} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

- If you want to type $n$ characters, for $n>5$. You may want to:

  - First type $\displaystyle \left(n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)$ characters, then copy paste $\displaystyle \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$ characters.
  - First type $\displaystyle \left(n-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)$ characters, then copy paste $\displaystyle \left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor$ characters twice.

As the above discussion shown that it is possible to get $x$ `a`'s in $g(x)$ steps. I can ensure that $g(x)\ge f(x)$ for any $x$. But I cannot show that $g(x)=f(x)$. And I have tested the function $g$ with every $x<2000$ with an referenced implementation, and it simply pass for all these testcases.

So what I'm wondering that if some one may either prove $g\equiv f$, or find a counterexample so $g(x)\ne f(x)$.

Comment: Or should it be $\min\{2 + f(n - \lfloor n/2\rfloor), 3 + f(n - 2 \lfloor n/3\rfloor)\}$? After all, to copy $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ characters and paste them takes two steps.

Comment: You would want to exclude (a) typing an extra character (b) pasting a shorter string and (c) pasting more than twice in a row.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Sorry for the typo. Just fixed.

Comment: @Henry I can see that (c) is trivial. And although no prove, i would likely to believe (a) is correct. But I cannot see the correctness about (b). As $f$ is not mono-increasing. build a longer string first and copy paste some shorter string should be reasonable attempt.

Comment: Because $f$ is not monotonic it is hard.  For example, if you want $f(52)$ your first approach is $10$ steps to get $26$ then $2$ steps to double it for $12$.  You would be better with $9$ steps to get $27$ then copy $25$ for $11$.  You get saved because $f(18)=8$ and $3$ more steps will give $52$ in $11$ steps.  I suspect it becomes monotonic at some point and it is probably easier to do the general proof above that point and worry separately about the special cases.

Comment: @RossMillikan - it does not seem to be monotonic: for example all the odds from $1945$ to $2187$ seem to need $21$ while all the evens from $1946$ to $2188$ seem to need $22$.  Perhaps the best you can do is say each step is $-1$ or $0$ or $+1$.

Comment: I'm late to the discussion, but if $n=2^p$ there's an obvious strategy in $p=\log_2(n)$ steps. Where's the catch? (If $n$ is not a power of two, find the closest and then apply some other strategy)

Comment: @lcv It's not too late, considering that there are still no answers here... Anyway, when $n=2^k$, $g(n)=2k$ for any $k>0$. And i believe $f(n)=2k$ too. But I cannot see how it may help me prove the correctness or find any counterexamples.

Comment: Actually I'm not so sure what is the question exactly. Can you make it a bit more clear?

Comment: @lcv I want a prove which show $\forall x\in\mathbb{N}^+: g(x)=f(x)$. OR an counterexample that $\exists x\in\mathbb{N}^+: g(x)\ne f(x)$

Comment: And $f$ Is the function that achieves the tasks in the minimal number of steps right? (But the algorithm is itself $f$, so $f$ is the shortest algorithm?)

Comment: @lcv Yes, $f(x)$ is the minimal steps needed to input $x$ letters into the editor. Word “function” only means a math function that mapping number of characters to number of steps in this question, not be confused with any code golf program functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fact 1:**
We may never paste more than two times in a row at the end:

If we ends in $C(r)V^{2k+1}$ with $k\geq 1$, replace by $C(r)VC(2r)V^{k}$, and we have $k+2 \leq 2k+1$.

If we ends in $C(r)V^{2k}$ with $k\geq 2$, replace by $C(r)VVC(2r)V^{k-1}$, and we have $k+2\leq 2k$.

By induction, we have our result.

**Corollary:** We have the induction:
$$g(n) = \min\left\{\min_{r\geq \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor} g(n-r)+2, \min_{r\geq \left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor} g(n-2r)+3\right\}$$

---

**Fact 2:** $g(n) \leq g(n+2)$

The optimal solution of $g(n+2)$ ends in $C(r)V$ or $C(r)VV$. We replace it by $C(r-2)V$ or $C(r-1)VV$ to upper bound $g(n)$ by $g(n+2)$.

**Corollary:**
If $g(n) > g(n+1)$ then $g(n+1)$ ends in $C(r)VV$

**Corollary:** We are left with an induction that relies on three cases (when we end in two pastes, there is only one case – the third one – because the other inductions are at least two steps away) :
$$g(n) = min \left\{g\left(n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)+2, g\left(n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor+1\right)+2,  g\left(n-2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)+3 \right\} $$

---

**Fact 3:** We can avoid the second case of the induction

Suppose that we get the second case of the induction, then we end in $C(r)VVC(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor-1)V$.

- If $r+\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor-1$ is even, we can rewrite this end as $C(r)VC((r+\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor-1)/2)VV$

We just need to verify that

$$(r+\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor-1)/2 \leq n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor+1 - r$$

We must have $3r \leq n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor+1$, so $r$ grows in $\mathcal{O}(\frac{n}{3})$ so the left hand side grows $\mathcal{O}(\frac{n}{3})$ and the right hand side grows $\Omega(n)$ thus we will verify the inequality for some sufficiently large $n$ (and probably not very large).

- Otherwise, we rewrite it as $C(r-1)VC((r+\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor)/2)VV$

As above, we can verify that it is well defined for some sufficiently large $n$

---

**Conclusion:**
We are thus left with the two cases that forms your conjecture.

Comment: Maybe the 4th term in min should be g(n−2⌊n/3⌋+1) instead of g(n−2⌊n/3⌋+2). or, maybe I misread the prove some how...

Comment: @tsh In fact, I think there is no 4th term, every other possible induction which ends in two pastes will be at least two steps away from $n-2\lfloor n/3\rfloor$

Comment: I didn't catch the idea bout "at least two steps away" about the $g(n-2\lfloor n/3 \rfloor+1)+3$. So I'm still confuse here. Another mirror issue is, to what i understand, $3r \le n-\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ seems require about $6r \le n-k$ for some $k$, not $3r$ (although this doesn't really matter.

Comment: The induction is $g(n-2r)$ for all $r$ starting from $\lfloor 
 n/3\rfloor$, so for $r=\lfloor 
 n/3\rfloor$, you will get $g(n-2\lfloor n/3\rfloor+2$, so two steps away. For $r$, we can probably improve the bound, my reasoning was that because we copied and pasted it, it must appears 3 times for $g(n-\lfloor 
 n/2\rfloor+1)$. I don't understand what you mean about $6r$.

Comment: $6r$ is used as $3r < n-\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \le (n+1)/2$, thus $6r\le n$.